# Suppress __init__.py in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse-plugin, pydev

How to suppress `__init__.py` from showing in the project tree [Eclipse PyDev]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the dropdown menu on the toolbar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>) and choose `Setup Custom Filters`. Here you should be able to add a custom filter for `__init__.py` files.

Comment: What I had to do is to change the perspective of Eclipse.
Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> PyDev. After that the button you talked about appeared. I was working in C/C++ perspective. Thanks a lot